# Failed while installing tfjs-node using macOS and node-gyp rebuild failed

Tags: tensorflow, npm, tensorflowjs

I'm trying to install tfjs-node via `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node` on my mac.

I'm getting following error while trying to installing it.

```
Error: node-gyp rebuild failed with: Error: Command failed: node-gyp rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /Users/ReffasCode/anaconda3/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:597:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ReffasCode/Desktop/ip2_ss19/Server/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, getting more information from https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp it seems like `node-gyp` is not supporting Python version 3.x.x is not supported.

So if you having the same error try to specify which Python version to use:

```
npm config set python /usr/bin/python
```